# How do you change the font of the Navigation Bar?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift2

How do you change the font of the Navigation Bar?

Comment: accept an answer that helped you, this will help you to get more help in future.

Answer (score 2):

try like attributes with `titleTextAttributes` property...

```
  let attributesDictionary = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "your font name", size: 24)!, NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.whiteColor()]
  UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = attributesDictionary
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code, this is written in Obj-C but you can get idea from here

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes: [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                           [UIColor colorWithRed:245.0/255.0 green:245.0/255.0 blue:245.0/255.0 alpha:1.0], NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                                                           [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-CondensedBlack" size:21.0], NSFontAttributeName, nil]];
```

for more options on customization you can check [this nice tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/customize-navigation-status-bar-ios-7/)

Answer (score 0):

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor redColor], NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"mplus-1c-regular" size:21]}];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna change the font of all navigation bar, you can do this in OC:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:
    @{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:22], // font size
     NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor yellowColor], // foreground color
     NSBackgroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor blackColor]}]; // background color
```

this in Swift:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = 
    [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont.systemFontOfSize(22), // font size
     NSBackgroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.yellowColor(), // background color
     NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.blackColor()] // foreground color
```

But if you just wanna change that of some specified view controllers, you can do this in OC:

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:
    @{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:22], 
      NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor yellowColor], 
      NSBackgroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor blackColor]}];
```

and this in Swift:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes =
        [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont.systemFontOfSize(22),
            NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.yellowColor(),
            NSBackgroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.blackColor()]
```

Hope these can be helpful.